# How to remove vertices from a graph?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I have 2 lists: list 1 is a list of vertices of a graph, says, {1,2,3,4,5} and list 2 keeps track of edges (i.e which vertex connects to which) such as {{1,2}, {2,3},{3,4},{4,1},{2,5}}. Now I want to remove some vertices in list 1 and I want that any edges in list 2 that have an end same as one of the removed vertices will also be removed. What would be the best way to do this in Mathematica? (I can do this easily in other languages like vb.net, but I still am trying to get my head on Mathematica)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are done easily with graph functions:

```
g = Graph[Range[5], {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 1, 2 <-> 5}];
```

[image]

```
g2 = VertexDelete[g, 1];
```

[image]

```
EdgeList[g2]
```

(*

{2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5}

*)

Of course this works as well if you want to delete more than one vertex, e.g., vertices 1 and 5:

```
g2 = VertexDelete[g, {1, 5}];
```

Answer (score 14):

Although using `Graph` and `VertexDelete` is tempting (and every sane person would try that first), it is by no means an efficient way of doing this. Here is a method that circumvents `Graph` and works directly on sparse adjacency matrices:

```
edges = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {2, 5}};
vertdel = {1, 4};

A = SparseArray[edges -> 1, {1, 1} Max[edges]];
a = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Partition[vertdel, 1] -> 0, {Length[A]}, 1]];
SparseArray[a.A.a]["NonzeroPositions"]
```

> {{2, 3}, {2, 5}}

Here `A` is the (nonsymmetric) adjacency matrix of the underlying graph and `a` is the diagonal matrix carrying the indicator function of the new index set on the diagonal. Then `a.A.a` is the (nonsymmetric) adjacency matrix of the resulting graph; we need to wrap it with `SparseArray` in order to enforce recomputation of the sparse array pattern so that the list of nonzero positions of the matrix corresponds to edges of the new graph.
(For those who are interested: The undocumented `` "SparseArray`" `` context contains many graph-related algorithms that work directly on (weighted) adjacency matrices and that are usually much faster than the `Graph`-based implementations.)

---

With a timing example, it is easier to realize that this is more efficient than applying `MemberQ` or to use `Graph` (and that `Graph` is so slow should be utterly embarassing for WRI).

Of course, using `SparseArray` for the adjacency matrix, I assume that the adjacency matrix is sparse...

Let's create the edge set of a random graph:

```
n = 10000;
m = 100000;
ndel = 1000;
G = RandomGraph[{n, m}];
edges = Developer`ToPackedArray[List @@@ EdgeList[G]];
vertdel = RandomSample[Span[1, n], ndel];
```

Here are the timings:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  MemberQedges = Complement[edges, Flatten[Select[edges, MemberQ[#]] & /@ vertdel, 1]];
  ]
```

> 131.84

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  g = Graph[Range[n], UndirectedEdge @@@ edges];
  gedges = EdgeList[VertexDelete[g, vertdel]];
  ]
```

> 9.80492

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  A = SparseArray[edges -> 1, {1, 1} Max[edges]]; 
  a = DiagonalMatrix[ SparseArray[Partition[vertdel, 1] -> 0, {Length[A]}, 1]]; 
  spedges = SparseArray[a.A.a]["NonzeroPositions"];
  ]
```

> 0.006572

Of course, we have to check whether all methods return essentially the same result:

```
Sort[spedges] == Sort[MemberQedges] == Sort[List @@@ gedges]
```

> True

Actually, already *constructing* the (old) graph `g` takes 20 times(!) longer than computing the edges of the new graph with the sparse matrix method...

Finally, as in all `Graph`-related threads, it is almost obligatory to mention Szabolcs' [`` "IGraphM`" ``](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) package. There we find the function `IGWeightedVertexDelete` that accomplishes the task with more acceptable speed. It may be slower than the `SparseArray` method but it preserves also a lot of structure of the old graph; this may be very useful in practice and comes -- of course -- at a certain cost.

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  g2 = IGWeightedVertexDelete[g, vertdel];
  ]
EdgeList[g2] == gedges
```

> 0.0746
>
> True

Comment: @chris Thanks for the reminder. I wrote that in -- as J.M. would say -- _gedanken Mathematica_.

Comment: This solution makes me realize how much there is to learn about Wolfram this year

Comment: As someone who hadn't quite understood the purpose of sparse arrays (until now) this is fascinating.

Comment: This answer is quite instructive. I came here because I was looking to see if anyone had mentioned that the functions for `Graph` are slow. I am finding that just using list manipulation on the edge list is quicker than using `VertexDelete` or `VertexContract` on simple graphs with like 6-4 vertices . Would you confirm that Graph is still slow ? Are there any functions that have a reasonable speed ? I do not understand why `Graph` is atomic if it is not that efficient. Maybe it is is efficient in memory more than speed ?

Comment: "I do not understand why Graph is atomic if it is not that efficient." Yes, me neither. For small graphs, in is maybe more efficient to directly work on the (dense!) adjacency matrix. For larger, but sparse graphs one can do quite a lot with their adjacency matrix represented by a `SparseArray`. However, manipulations that change the nonzero structure of sparse matrix are typically also not very efficient. In general, the most suitable data structure depends on the type of graph and on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thank you I am not used to working with sparse arrays and especially not with graphs so any information is quite helpful. I looked into the SparseArray` context as recommended in the answer but I am not sure I found an equivalent to VertexDelete,EdgeDelete, or VertexContract. I did see `FindHamiltionian` path. I have many small graphs to work with. If I take the disjoint union of these graphs in the idea of doing "parallel" graph computations on the single graph, the resulting adjacency matrix would be artificially sparse.

Comment: Not sure if that would be a good idea to use SparseArray computations on multiple small graphs at once rather than calling Graph computations on each.

Comment: As I said, for small graphs you better use dense adjacency matrices. Or you operate directly on the edge list (which is just a list of pairs). In the latter case it might be a good idea to use an n x 2 array with n large enough to hold the maximal number of edges. Then you put your m edges into the first m rows and additionally store the number m. This way you don't have to reallocate the matrices. And this also allows you to use `Compile` to compile performance critical code parts to machine code.

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** An alternative way to use `SparseArray` with a better speed:

Using Henrik's timing setup

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[A2 = SparseArray[edges -> 1, {1, 1} Max[edges]]; 
  A2[[All, vertdel]] = A2[[vertdel, All]] = 0;
  spedges2 = A2["NonzeroPositions"];]
```

> 0.00570508

versus

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[A = SparseArray[edges -> 1, {1, 1} Max[edges]];
  a = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Partition[vertdel, 1] -> 0, {Length[A]}, 1]];
  spedges = SparseArray[a.A.a]["NonzeroPositions"];]
```

> 0.0119241

```
spedges == spedges2
```

> True

**Original answer:**

```
edges = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {2, 5}};
```

A few more alternatives:

```
Select[edges, FreeQ[1]]
Pick[edges, FreeQ[1] /@ edges]
DeleteCases[edges, {_, 1} | {1, _}]
List @@@ EdgeList[VertexDelete[edges, 1]]
```

all give

> {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {2, 5}}

Comment: Your first three suggestions only work for removing a single vertex.

Comment: @geordie, if you want to remove a list of vertices, say `{1,2}`, you can use `1|2` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 4):

The following works for removing several vertices and corresponding edges:

```
verts = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
edges = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {2, 5}};

vertdel = {1, 4}
verts2 = Complement[verts, vertdel]
edges2 = Complement[edges, Flatten[Select[edges, MemberQ[#]] & /@ vertdel, 1]]
```

> {1, 4}
>
> {2, 3, 5}
>
> {{2, 3}, {2, 5}}